# How do I reference a site by ID using IIS7 APPCMD?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, configuration

I know how to reference a site by name to stop and start it? For example:

```
appcmd stop site /site.name:"Microsoft SharePoint Administration"
```

How do I reference a site using its IIS ID? I tried these variations:

```
appcmd start stop /site.id:2
appcmd start stop /site.id:"2"
appcmd start stop /site.id:2
appcmd start site /section:sites /[id='2']
```

However they all return the following error:

> `ERROR ( message:Must specify the SITE object with identifier. )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm - this works:

```
appcmd.exe list site -id:2
```

This doesn't:

```
appcmd.exe stop site -id:2
```

Comment: Annoying isn't it?